# How do I set a variable to quotations in python?

Tags: python

How could I set a variable to quotations in python? It would go in this script:

```
var = "(quotations)"
if let == var:
 ...
```

Comment: Can you post code where you would use this?

Comment: should be var quotation = '"'  
that's a single quote then a double quote then a single quote

Comment: `if let = var:` or `if let == var:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to set a variable to the string `"`. Here are some:

```
var = "\""
var = '"'
var = '''"'''
```

In each case, `var` is a one-character string. The first (and only) character is `"`.